# OpenLayers vector layer remove all features

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, features

I have a map (using OpenLayers) and a vector layer containing features(points). Sometimes I need to remove all features from the vector layer. When I use

```
vectorLayer.removeAllFeatures()
```

then it removes all features from only one zoom level. When I change zoom level, I see all my features again. How can I remove all features from all zoom levels?

Answer (score 3):

How were the features loaded in the layer in the first place?

Unless the features were added on the client (i.e. in a Javascript function written by you), when the extent changes the default behavior for Vector layers backed by WFS is to fetch new features from the server.

You can customize the behavior of the Vector layer with regard to remote sources by providing a properly configured [strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy-js.html#OpenLayers.Strategy). Examples like [this one](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-spatial-filter.html) are available in the [examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) page.

Comment: Yes, added in the client by js function. What strategy in this case should I use?

Comment: It looks llike you are using BBOX strategy. In your case you should use Fixed strategy.

Comment: Or deactivate your strategy, when you need to use BBOX.

Comment: @Bob can you include the code in your question? It's next to impossible w/o it.

Answer (score 3):

Well I had the same problem too and solved it using the function `destroyFeatures`

```
vectorLayer.destroyFeatures();
```

but then the features have to be recreated.